# Matlab paths and file handling with packages and class folders

Tags: matlab, path, namespace-package

So I have the following (simplified) project structure.

```
scripts/
   client.m
src/
    +estimators/
        @estimator1/
            3party/
                shell_script.sh
            estimator1.m
```

Basically, what I try to do is, calling `estimator1.m` from `client.m`. This is working very well, no issues. However, from within `estimator1.m` I try to call `shell_script.sh`. The problem, relative paths do not work since it is always looking from the path `client.m` is called.

What I tried from `estimator1.m` is:

```
pathToScript = fullfile('3Party','shell_script');
system(pathToScript);
```

I would really like to avoid absolute paths since I'd like this package to be used by others as well. So hardcoding paths to my home directory is not good.

Answer (score 4):

Use `mfilename('fullpath')` to get the full path of the currently executing file. Use `fileparts` to get just the directory part. Putting it together,

```
scriptdir = fullfile (fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')), '3Party');
```

Comment: I was just about to start typing this same answer. :)

Comment: This is the way. My convention is to create a `resources/` subdirectory underneath the `@blah` directory for a class to hold any data or non-Matlab executable files that are "owned" and managed by that class.

Comment: Do you know how this works with class inheritance? I have a parent class, lets say `abstractEstimator` and all `estimatorX` classes are inheriting from the abstract/parent class. So I thought the smartest way would be to add a function to retrieve `scriptdir`  would be to add it to the parent class -> only implement it once but accessible by all child classes. However, this only gives the position of the parent class and not the class where it is actually called from.

Comment: `mfilename` knows nothing about inheritance, it just tells you which actual file is currently executing. Unfortunately, this means that if you want each child class to have a separate `scriptdir`, you'll need each class to have its own call to `mfilename`.

Comment: I suppose the other option for class hierarchies is to consider something along the lines of `which(class(obj))` - this should tell you where the child class lives even if you run this in a base class method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an additional answer to the one by @Edric. My second issue was that I wanted to implement the feature in the parent class since it is a functionality used by all child classes. The proposed answer is perfect when you have the function implemented in the class itself. However:

```
scriptdir = fullfile (fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')));
```

would always return the location of my parent class. So I implemented following in the parent class to retrieve the correct location in child classes:

```
function classdir= getClassDir(obj)             
    [classdir, ~, ~] = fileparts(which(class(obj)));         
end
```